# OAuth::RequestProxy::UnknownRequestType (ActionDispatch::Request): error with IMS::LTI::ToolProvider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

I did update for rails app form 4 to 5 recently.

Then IMS::LTI::ToolProvider is not working properly.

Here is the code:

```
private_key = res[:body]["private_key"]
provider = IMS::LTI::ToolProvider.new(public_key, private_key, params.to_unsafe_h)
unless provider.valid_request?(request)
  if provider.context_student? || provider.institution_student?
    return render :participant_wait_for_activity
  else
    return render :invalid_key
  end
end
```

I got an error when `provider.valid_request?(request)` is excuted.

Here is the error:
OAuth::RequestProxy::UnknownRequestType (ActionDispatch::Request):